# Invalid JSON-LD?

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I have been playing with JSON-LD a while and am wondering your usage is correct? Shouldn't @context contain a URL? The validator seems to accept both.. the playground on json-ld.org strangely neither. It returns the following error:

> {"name":"jsonld.InvalidUrl","message":"Derefencing a URL did not
>   result in a valid JSON-LD object. Possible causes are an inaccessible
>   URL perhaps due to a same-origin policy (ensure the server uses CORS
>   if you are using client-side JavaScript), too many redirects, or a
>   non-JSON
>   response.","details":{"url":"http://schema.org","cause":{"name":"jsonld.LoadContextError","message":"URL
>   could not be dereferenced, an error
>   occurred.","details":{"url":"http://schema.org","cause":""}}}}

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context `schema.org` is correctly understood by Google and the decision to drop the `http://` was made in order to simplify the developers' lives.

Check this W3C thread for the complete discussion about this implementation: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-rdf-wg/2013May/0183.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link Claudio, will read the thread later. I'm not sure it simplifies developers' lives, in contrast, it confused me.